# PHP_SELF not working as expected

Tags: php, html, forms

```
//index.php
    <?php
        $root=realpath(__DIR__);
        require($root.'/admin_header.php');

        if(isset($_GET['action'])){
            switch($_GET['action']){
                case "admin_add":
                    require($root.'\admin_add.php');    
                    break;
            }
        }
    ?>

//admin_add.php
    <?php
    ...verification and sql add code...
    ?>
    <?php
        function add_form(){
    ?>
           <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post" id="add_form">
              ...........
           </form>
    <?php
       }
    ?>
```

For testing purpose i manually type on browser index.php?action=admin_add but when i submit the form instead of going to index.php?action=admin_add it goes to index.php. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` will have what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source. You'll see PHP_SELF does not have the value you expect. You'll need to add your query string (`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`). Or better yet, leave the  `action` attribute blank. That defaults to the current URL.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="add_form">
```

Comment: Leaving action atrribute worked but doesn't it have problem on security like injection of scripts